# NSToolbarDelegate Error?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstoolbar

Im creating a NSWindowController and its window programatically. So i create a simple NSToolbar with:

```
NSToolbar *toolbar = [[NSToolbar alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"PreferencesToolbar"];

[toolbar setDisplayMode:NSToolbarDisplayModeIconAndLabel];
[toolbar setAllowsUserCustomization:NO];
[toolbar setAutosavesConfiguration:NO];

[self.window setToolbar:toolbar];

[toolbar release];
```

Which all works fine, but when I add
    [toolbar setDelegate:self];

I get the following error:

ERROR: invalid delegate  (does not implement all required methods), and so can not be used! (To debug, add a breakpoint to NSToolbarError

According to NSToolbarDelegate there are no required methods, so what is going wrong here?

Comment: does `self` conforms to `NSToolbarDelegate` protocol ? if not, declare your controller to conform to it, even without implementing methods.

Comment: Yes it does: @interface PreferencesWindowController : NSWindowController <NSToolbarDelegate>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to make the toolbar work with your `NSWindowController` subclass as its delegate, you must declare it to conform to `NSToolbarDelegate` protocol :

```
@interface MyController : NSWindowController <NSToolbarDelegate>
```

Also, from the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSToolbarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you must ensure that some *are* implemented, even if they are optional, because you created the toolbar programmatically. They are :

```
-(NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar
    itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier
willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag;

-(NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar;

-(NSArray *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar;
```

> **Important** While this method is marked as @optional in the NSToolbarDelegate protocol , it must be implemented if the associated toolbar is created programatically. Toolbars created in Interface Builder can implement this method to augment functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the 3x "Important" in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Following the great answer provided, the **Swift** version of the **required** methods:

```swift
func toolbar(_ toolbar: NSToolbar,
               itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier,
               willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool) -> NSToolbarItem?
    
func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier]
    
func toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier]
```